# OpenSSL Blocking Sockets SSL_read blocks

Tags: sockets, ssl, openssl, blocking

I am using blocking sockets in OpenSSL connection. SSL_read blocks sometimes for few seconds. In server - BIO_write is used to send data in variable buffer size. In client - first SSL_read to get buffer size succeeds but following SSL_read to get buffer data blocks for few seconds(this issue is simulated after 2 to 3mins) even though data sent successfully. I wait on poll() to invoke client read function. How to correct these problem in blocking sockets?

Server Code

```
void process_and_send() {
     // sending variable size buffer each time
     // sbuf - first 4 bytes contains sbuf size information
     send_data(sbuf, sbufSize);
}


void send_data(void *sbuf, int pending_len) {
        while(pending_len > 0) {
                result = BIO_write(bio, sbuf, pending_len);
                if(result == 0) {
                        attempts = 0;
                        LOG_D("%s", log_str(SSL_CONN_CLOSE));
                        SSL_FN_TRACE("connection closed\n");
                        break;
                }
                else if(result < 0) {
                        LOG_I("%s", log_str(SSL_WRITE_FAIL));
                        SSL_FN_TRACE("BIO_write fail\n");
                        if(errno == EINTR) {
                                continue;
                        }
                        if(errno == EAGAIN) {
                                attempts++;
                                continue;
                        }
                        if(errno == EWOULDBLOCK) {
                                attempts++;
                                continue;
                        }
                        break;
                }
                else {
                        BIO_flush(bio);
                        pending_len -= result;
                        sbuf += result;
                }
        }  
 }
```

Client Code

```
// wait on poll() and call receive_and_process
void receive_and_process() {
     int rbufSize = 0;
     // get the size of data to read
     receive_data((void *)&rbufSize, sizeof(Int));
     // this call blocks for few seconds
     receive_data(rbuf, rbufSize);
}

void receive_data(void *rbuf, int pending_len) {
    while(pending_len > 0) {
                    result = SSL_read(ssl, rbuf, pending_len);
            if(result == 0) {
                    LOG_D("%s", log_str(SSL_CONN_CLOSE));
                    SSL_FN_TRACE("connection closed\n");
                    return NULL;
            }
            else if(result < 0) {
                    if(errno == ETIMEDOUT) {
                            SSL_FN_ERROR("SSL read timeout:  \n");
                            continue;
                    }
                    if(errno == EINTR) {
                            continue;
                    }
                    if(errno == EAGAIN) {
                            continue;
                    }
                    if(errno == EWOULDBLOCK) {
                            continue;
                    }

                    SSL_FN_ERROR("SSL read fail error no:  %s\n",
                                    ERR_reason_error_string(ERR_get_error()));
                    LOG_I("%s", log_str(SSL_READ_FAIL));
                    return NULL;
            }
            pending_len -= result;
            rbuf += result;
            FN_ERROR("after read full data pending len %d\n", pending_len);
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree. I/O via a blocking socket blocks. Your question?

Comment: why it blocks? even though data sent successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Well, for starters, your client code can't compile as shown, because `receive_data()` has a `void` return type, so `return NULL` is a compiler error.  Also, you can't use the `+=` operator on a `void*` pointer, that is also a compiler error.

Beside that, if `SSL_read()` returns < 0, you need to use `SSL_get_error()` instead of `errno` to find out why it failed.  Don't use `errno` unless `SSL_get_error()` returns `SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL`.  If `SSL_get_error()` returns `SSL_ERROR_SSL`, use `ERR_get_error()` and related functions instead.  And, make sure you are handling the `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ` and `SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE` errors.

Also, when sending multi-byte integers, you have to deal with endian issues if you are sending across machine boundaries.  Best to use functions like `htonl()` and `ntohl()` to send integers over the connection in network byte order.

Try something more like this:

Server:

```
void process_and_send() {
     // sending variable size buffer each time
     // sbuf - DO NOT store the size information in the first 4 bytes!
     //        handle the size separately...
     int32_t size = htonl(sbufSize);
     if (send_data(&size, sizeof(size)))
         send_data(sbuf, sbufSize);
}

bool send_data(void *sbuf, int pending_len) {
    unsigned char *pbuf = (unsigned char *) sbuf;
    while (pending_len > 0) {
        result = BIO_write(bio, pbuf, pending_len);
        if (result > 0) {
            BIO_flush(bio);
            pbuf += result;
            pending_len -= result;
        }
        else if (result == 0) {
            attempts = 0;
            LOG_D("%s", log_str(SSL_CONN_CLOSE));
            SSL_FN_TRACE("connection closed\n");
            return false;
        }
        else if (!BIO_should_retry(bio)) {
            LOG_I("%s", log_str(SSL_WRITE_FAIL));
            SSL_FN_TRACE("BIO_write fail\n");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            ++attempts;
        }
    }  
    return true;
}
```

Client:

```
// wait on poll() and call receive_and_process
void receive_and_process() {
     int32_t rbufSize = 0;
     // get the size of data to read
     if (receive_data(&rbufSize, sizeof(rbufSize))) {
         rbufSize = ntohl(rbufSize);
         // TODO: make sure rbuf is at least rbufSize in size...
         receive_data(rbuf, rbufSize);
     }
}

bool receive_data(void *rbuf, int pending_len) {
    unsigned char *pbuf = (unsigned char *) rbuf;
    while (pending_len > 0) {
        result = SSL_read(ssl, pbuf, pending_len);
        if (result > 0) {
            pbuf += result;
            pending_len -= result;
            FN_ERROR("after read full data pending len %d\n", pending_len);
        }
        else {
            result = SSL_get_error();
            if (result == SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN) {
                LOG_D("%s", log_str(SSL_CONN_CLOSE));
                SSL_FN_TRACE("connection closed\n");
            }
            else {
                if (result == SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ) {
                    // TODO: use select() to wait for the socket to be readable before trying again...
                    continue;
                }
                else if (result == SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE) {
                    // TODO: use select() to wait for the socket to be writable before trying again...
                    continue;
                }
                else if (result == SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL) {
                    if ((errno == EINTR) || (errno == EAGAIN) || (errno == EWOULDBLOCK)) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (errno == ETIMEDOUT) {
                        SSL_FN_ERROR("SSL read timeout:  \n");
                        continue;
                    }

                    SSL_FN_ERROR("SSL read fail error no:  %d\n", errno);
                }
                else if (result == SSL_ERROR_SSL) {
                    SSL_FN_ERROR("SSL read fail error no:  %s\n",
                        ERR_reason_error_string(ERR_get_error()));
                }
                else {
                    SSL_FN_ERROR("SSL read fail error no:  %d\n", result);
                }
                LOG_I("%s", log_str(SSL_READ_FAIL));
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Remy. I did changes in my code as you mentioned. But SSL_read blocks sometimes for more than 2000 milliseconds even though data sent successfully.

Comment: @ArunrajShanmugam then you are likely not reading the data in the correct format. A blocking read will block if you ask for more bytes than is actually sent, such as if you misread a data size. Double check your reading logic

Comment: Ok I will debug and this issue is simulated often when the server receives data from multiple clients.

Comment: It looks like read call to get the size of data `receive_data(&rbufSize, sizeof(rbufSize)))`  itself blocks for few seconds.